# get NSDicitionary value as NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, api, instagram

I am fetching user-id from Instagram JSON API.

It return only one value as Dictionary valueForKeyPath.

How I could convert it to string. I need to use the userid with some operations on Instagram.

I tried to convert it by this way

```
NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"id"]];
```

The URL is coming not like string and I can't reconnect to Instagram with url like below:

> URL: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/(
>       123456 )/media/recent?access_token=567890.asasasddsdsdsdsdsadsdsdasd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to get the value from the array.  I guess it at index 0

```
NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"id"][0]];
```

or

```
NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"id"] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

because if the array is nil the program will crash with the first code.  Let me know if it worked

As @Paulw11 said you don't need the stringWithFormat because string is in the array 
the line of code should be

```
NSString *userId = [[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"id"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: You don't need the stringWithFormat - stringWithFormat with a format of %@ is redundant.

Comment: Great! I updated the answer as suggested by @Paulw11

Comment: @yan Actually this one working NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"id"][0]]; on the last one app crashing.

Comment: @Yan "because if the array is nil the program will crash with the first code." No, the two lines are equivalent and the code will behave identically if the array is nil.

Comment: @jlehr No, there is a slight difference. The first version will always give you an NSString (possibly empty) while the second may give an NSString or nil. Good defensive programming should check for a nil value and handle it accordingly, however

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe Yan was contrasting his first two examples, not the third.

Comment: @Paulw11 but it doesn't.  I have checked and seen that. First one is ok. By the way, I am checking JSON Data for nil.

Comment: @Yan I have also checked again this one: NSString *userId = [[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"id"] objectAtIndex:0]; it also worked. Less code :)